# WPF. How to insert data from EXCEL to sql table (advanced)?

Tags: excel, wpf, sql-server-2014

My Excel file contains data like this:

```
Name      ID       Contact
---------------------------
John      3        01542954
Smith     6        7450142
Dan       8        5486295
```

This is my table (`tblinfo`) in SQL Server with two columns (`Customer` and `Contact`).

I want to insert data from

- Name -> Customer
- Contact -> Contact

I tried to search so much. But almost things that they tutorial about Winforms NOT WPF

I'm using VS 2015, SQL Server 2014, Office 2010

Comment: excel file. sql server database. why does WPF or WinForms make any difference??

Comment: @ASh Winform have property: datagrid.Rows[i].Cell[0].Value. but WPF doesn't

Comment: why would you need datagrid (or any other ui object) to get data from excel and insert into sql table?? they are different data storages. data can be migrated without display

Answer (score 0):

Use following method to generate the `DataTable` from Excel sheet.

```
public static DataTable ConvertExcelToDataTable(string FileName)  
{  
    DataTable dtResult = null;  
    int totalSheet = 0; //No of sheets on excel file  
    using(OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(@  
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';"))  
    {  
        objConn.Open();  
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();  
        OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();  
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
        DataTable dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);  
        string sheetName = string.Empty;  
        if (dt != null)  
        {  
            var tempDataTable = (from dataRow in dt.AsEnumerable()  
            where!dataRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase")  
            select dataRow).CopyToDataTable();  
            dt = tempDataTable;  
            totalSheet = dt.Rows.Count;  
            sheetName = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();  
        }  
        cmd.Connection = objConn;  
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";  
        oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);  
        oleda.Fill(ds, "excelData");  
        dtResult = ds.Tables["excelData"];  
        objConn.Close();  
        return dtResult; //Returning Dattable  
    }  
}
```

Use this `DataTable` to prepare query to your SQL database.